# Converting issue Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdata

```
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [encryptedStr UTF8String] length: [encryptedStr length]];
```

I want to convert the above string to Swift.

```
var myRequestData = NSData(bytes: encryptedStr.UTF8String(), length: encryptedStr.length())!
```

I have tried something above but it is not working in Xcode 7.3.1.

I have also tried to convert using https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main but failed.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working in xcode 7.3.1`? What's the problem? Please update the question with this  information.

Comment: above is my Objective-c code and i want to convert is for swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var myRequestData = NSData(bytes: (encryptedStr as NSString).UTF8String, length: encryptedStr.characters.count)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh Verma

Comment: NSString *encVal = [ccTool encryptRSA:myRequestString key:rsaKey];
    encVal = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)encVal,
                                                                        NULL,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));

Comment: can you please also convert this ?

Comment: @ZetrixWeb Looks like you are using some component which is written in objective c (for encryption). So firstly add a bridge to those components. Then try integrating these components.

Comment: i have already added i am trying to integrate CCAvenue in swift

Comment: CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is deprecated, So better use it like let charset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!").invertedSet
    let escaped = orig.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charset)

Comment: This all i am doing to integrate CCAvenue Payment Gateway in swift , have you ever implemented ?

Comment: You can have look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215338/string-encoding-swift

Comment: `encryptedStr.characters.count` is *not* the correct value to pass as the length parameter to `NSData`. Try it with `encryptedStr = "€"`. The correct result should be `<e282ac>`, not `<e2>`.